# Diff-command: doesn't print lines that are different but still says the two files are different

Tags: unix, diff

I'm using the diff command to compare two text files. They need to be literally matched.

So I use the diff:

`diff binary.out binary.expected`

(By the way, those files are NOT binary files. They are text file. I call them binary because that's the name of the project)

and got

`Binary files binary.out and binary.expected differ`

When I use another diff tool, the smartest of all (AKA human), and there's really nothing different between the two files.

Does anyone happen to know what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: `diff` has a narrow notion of "text".  You may have special characters that aren't actually all that special:  accents, carriage returns.

Comment: I don't think my textfiles have special characters. All they contain are the word "BINARY SUM", digit '0's and '1's and a few newline characters. But even so, that doesn't explain while diff considered my files binary files

Comment: If you don't have the LF/CR (line feed/ carriage return) sequence at the end of each string of your file then on Windows most text editors would treat these files as binaries. These symbols are invisible when you are looking on the text in the text mode, but try to look on the files in the binary mode and you should see 0xD 0xA at the end of each line.

Comment: or if both files where created on unix and never touched by windows or FTP configured for windows, the line break char is just the 0xA. Good luck.

Comment: make a binary dump (using `hexdump`) of your files, it's 99% sure that your production process put there some \0 characters which you don't see but makes diff think they are binary files. it's common mistake when writing files and forgetting to remove trailing zero in strings / characters arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to ignore white space in the diff options.

It may also see Unicode characters and interpret that as binary. See if your diff tool has an option to force text mode.

Answer (score 8):

`diff` from [diffutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/diffutils.html) says the following about text/binary:

> `diff` determines whether a file is text or binary by checking the
>   first few bytes in the file; the exact number of bytes is system
>   dependent, but it is typically several thousand.  If every byte in
>   that part of the file is non-null, `diff` considers the file to be
>   text; otherwise it considers the file to be binary.

hence GNU diff have a quite open definition of what is text, and the use of the `--text` option to force it to treat the file as text should seldom be needed.

Have you checked if `binary.out` or `binary.expected` contains null characters? What version is your diff program?