# Git Diff Returns Binary Files Differ but no actual lines

Tags: git, diff

I'm doing:

```
git diff HEAD -- myfle.txt
```

and getting back:

> git diff --git a/myfile.txt b/myfile.txt 
>   index ....
>   Binary Files a/myfile.txt b/myfile.txt Differ

"Binary Files Differ" .. but no print-out of the actual lines changed.  What Am I doing wrong?

I'm also trying this between branches (i.e. git diff DEV QA -- myfile.txt) same result.

Comment: Could be different line endings?

Comment: No.  I've made real line changes

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10324677/1512654

Comment: If your files are stored as UTF-16, Git will believe they are binary, since every other byte tends to be zero.

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009104/446792?

Comment: What does 'file myfile.txt' say? Is it for example UTF16?

Comment: Should mention that recent git has a solution exactly in the (non-standard) encoding case

Comment: @EyalZinder Did you find more info on this?  Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Change the encoding of your file to UTF-8.
If you still don't see the diff then stage the file with `git add myfle.txt`, edit the file and do `git diff` again